# SharePoint not finding users in trusted domain

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-accounts, trusted-domain

We are using SharePoint Online with Office 365.  We recently acquired another company who had their own domain....we'll call us "domainus" and them "domainthem".  We now have a 2-way trust between both domains.  But despite that, SharePoint on 'domainus' does not see people in 'domainthem'.  People lookup fields don't find them, Delve doesn't find them...it makes me figure that "everyone except internal users" is only including users on 'domainus'.

How do I get our SharePoint online to include and see users in both domains??

I did try searching, but couldn't find anything pertaining to SharePoint Online in Office 365 with 2-way trust.

Note our users are in a local Active Directory which is synced to Azure.

Would this be resolved by migrating domainthem's SharePoint into ours?  And if so, what does that entail??

Thanks!

Comment: How your user accounts are set up? Are they in Azure AD or Local AD and syncing them in Azure. There is no 2 way trust in Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. You have 2 options. 
1. Migrate users to single domain that is synced with Azure. 
2. Create new Azure AD to sync with domainthem and connect it to your office 365 tenant.

[This link provides step for option 2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-multiple-domains-to-Office-365-2d2fa996-b760-411d-a5cc-190d63f13207#ID0EAABAAA=_Step_1)